# How to get Handle propertyToolStripProgressBar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to get Handle property of ToolStripProgressBar  c# desktop?

I need it for method
SetWindowTheme(toolStripProgressBar.Handle, null, null);

This progress bar is contained in status strip.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 Dim h As System.IntPtr = ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Handle
```